# Why is my if-else statement not executing correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I got a question why my if-else statement is not working.

I got a form with a text input, and when a user types in the size they want it should live edit the picture. I'm using the addclass and removeclass methods from jQuery. This is my script:

```
function slide() {
    var n = Number(document.getElementById('Getal1').value)

    if (n >= 101 && n < 201)
        $(openDiv1());

    else if(n > 200)
        $(openDiv2());

    else if(n >= 0 && n < 101)
        $(closeDiv());

    else {
        alert("You did not enter a number!")
    }
}

$(function openDiv1() {

    $( "#ombouw_wrap" ).addClass( "Addclass_ombouw_wrap_2block", 1, callback );
    return false;
});

function callback() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $( "#midden" ).removeClass( "Addclass_ombouw_wrap_1block Addclass_ombouw_wrap_3block" );
    }, 0 );
}

$(function openDiv2() {

    $( "#ombouw_wrap" ).addClass( "Addclass_ombouw_wrap_3block", 1, callback );
    return false;
});

function callback() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $( "#midden" ).removeClass( "Addclass_ombouw_wrap_1block Addclass_ombouw_wrap_2block" );
    }, 0 );
}

$(function closeDiv() {

    $( "#ombouw_wrap" ).addClass( "Addclass_ombouw_wrap_1block", 1, callback );
    return false;
});

function callback() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $( "#midden" ).removeClass( "Addclass_ombouw_wrap_2block Addclass_ombouw_wrap_3block" );
    }, 0 );
}

window.onload = closeDiv;
```

And this is my HTML code:

```
Lengte: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="numeric" onKeyup="slide()" id="Getal1" onKeyPress="return checkIt(evt)">
x Hoogte: <input type="text" ID="Getal2" onKeyPress="return checkIt(evt)">
x Diepte: <input type="text" ID="Getal3" onKeyPress="return checkIt(evt)">
</form>
```

When you reload the page, you see it is not starting with closedivs, but it starts straight with adding classes without executing the if-else statement.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're not using brackets for your if else if statements.

Comment: just a suggestion for your code. Always use english in your code. Like ID="Getal2". You should use english for it, as it might get used/edited by someone non-dutch (like in this case on stackoverflow). It makes more sense for the code. Just a suggestion from one dutch to the other :)

Comment: like if (n>=101 && n<201) openDiv1(); or do i need to add brackets?

Comment: @jayp brackets are not needed with 1 line if-else statements (1 line to execute)

Comment: They're not needed, but the way he has written the code is inconsistent. Brackets after some statements, no brackets after others. That was my point. Hence a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When you reload the page, you see it is not starting with closedivs, but it starts straight with adding classes without executing the if-else statement.

This is because jQuery treats `$(function)` as a handy form of [`$.ready(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/): the function-object passed is executed *on page load*.

That is, `$(function openDiv1() {...})` defines a function-object which is then passed to jQuery to execute automatically when the page loads. Instead, remove the functions from `$(...)`. For instance, `function openDiv1() {...}` will suffice. (This will also fix the errors with not being able to call `openDiv1` -- since it is a function-expression it will not be assigned to a variable/property in scope.)

---

The following describes an issue with the `slide` function.

JavaScript does some coercions; the following show why the else branch will never be reached:

```
Number("")         // same as Number(0)
Number("") >= 0    // true
```

But really, please don't use `Number` (it's a wrapper-object for `number`), consider `parseInt(str, 10)` as a replacement. As an added bonus, `parseInt("", 10)` evaluates to `NaN` (not 0) and since `NaN >= 0` is false, this will fix the initial problem.

```
function slide(){
    var n = parseInt(document.getElementById('Getal1').value, 10)
    if (n >= 0 && n <= 100) {
        $(closeDiv())
    } else if (n > 100 && n <= 200) {
        $(openDiv1())
    } else if (n > 200) {
        $(openDiv2())
    } else {
        alert("You did not enter a number!")
    }
}
```

Also pay attention to the consistency changes I added. The brackets are not necessary, but I find it aides in writing in a consistent well-formatted/well-indented style. Other things to pay attention to are ordering of if/else statements as well as the comparissons (keep it "flowing").

Happy coding.

Comment: well if changed mine code now into yourse but still it aint staying on closediv and filling all classes to the div..

Comment: @user968588 There was another problem as well, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are wrapping your functions in `$()` which will execute them when you are trying to define them...

```
// alerts 1
$(function myFunc(){ alert(1) })
```

You need to define your functions before your if/else statements, and just like this...

```
// does not execute until called
function myFunc(){ ... }
```

Comment: You are warapping in `$()` but you should not be doing this. The problem is this: `$(function openDiv1() { ... })` which does not define a function, but executes the function instead. You should define your functions as I specify.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a Javascript programmer, but I believe you are missing some braces on your IF/ELSE statements. The correct syntax should be, according to [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp):

```
if (condition1){
    Handle condition1
    }
else if (condition2){
    Handle condition2
    }
else{
    Handle the rest
    }
```

Of course if this isn't the case, and braces aren't needed, then I hope someone else can help you :).